# Terraform: how to import AWS cross-account resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How do I import an existing AWS resource into Terraform state, where that resource exists within a different account?

```
terraform import module.mymodule.aws_iam_policy.policy arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/mypolicy
```

gives the following error:

```
Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object

While attempting to import an existing object to aws_iam_policy.policy, the
provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing
objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is
associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use
"terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.
```

The resource was created in one account using a different provisioner defined within a module called `mymodule`:

```
module "mymodule" {
    // ... define variables for the module
}

// within the module
provider "aws" {
  alias = "cross-account"
  region = "eu-west-2"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = var.provider_role_arn
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  provider = "aws.cross-account"
  name        = var.policy-name
  path        = var.policy-path
  description = var.policy-description

  policy = var.policy-document
}
```

How do I import cross-account resources?

Update: using the `-provider` flag, I get a different error:

```
Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with module.mymodule.aws_iam_policy.policy (import
id "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/somepolicytoimport") its original provider
configuration at provider.aws.cross-account is required, but it has been
removed. This occurs when a provider configuration is removed while objects
created by that provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider
configuration to destroy
module.mymodule.aws_iam_policy.policy (import id
"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/somepolicytoimport"), after which you can remove
the provider configuration again.
```

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: Latest version (0.12.12)

Comment: You shouldn't need to use [`-provider=aws.cross-account`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/import.html#provider-provider) since 0.12.10 but it might be worth trying to see if that helps things.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR that gives a different error, see edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple provider configurations if you have credentials for the another account.

```
# This is used by default
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "another_account"
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "another-account-access-key"
  secret_key = "another-account-secret-key"
}

# To use the other configuration
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  provider = aws.another_account

  # ...
}
```

Here the documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assume the role of the second account as follows.

```
provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_NAME"
    session_name = "SESSION_NAME"
    external_id  = "EXTERNAL_ID"
  }
}
```

[1] : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html

Comment: If you read that same link you'll see that those are optional so this isn't what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is optional but you can apply the assume_role of the other account. This is the point.

Comment: They have the assume role bit setup already. You just added 2 optional fields for assuming a role which you don't need at all and are just for identifying the session in CloudTrail.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error while trying to import AWS acm certificate.

As the first step, before importing the resource, you need to create its configuration in the root module (or other relevant module):

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

Or you'll got the following error:

> Error: resource address "aws_acm_certificate.cert" does not exist in
> the configuration.

Then you can import the resource by providing its relevant arn:

```
$ terraform import aws_acm_certificate.cert <certificate-arn>
```

Like @ydaetskcoR mentioned in the comments - you don't need to assume the role of the second account if you're using `v0.12.10+`.

But Terraform do need Access credentials to the second account - so please make sure you provide the relevant account's credentials (and not the source account credentials) or you'll be stuck with the 
  `Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object` 
  for a few hours like me (: